# API INTEGRATION for azure devops git on snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to use snowflake devops to link a azure devops git repository. Does "CREATE OR REPLACE API INTEGRATION" work with azure devops git or only github?

Comment: Isn’t git integration still in private preview? Assuming it is, presumably you’ve had it enabled in your Snowflake account and have direct contact with the product manager - so I’d ask them